# Rails application keeps crashing, with no server or client error visible

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, web, crash

My rails application crashed regularly (after 10-20 minutes of use). I've been watching the console and network (in chrome) and nothing comes up. The site either stops responding or goes all white, and then the browser tab crashes.

I have only managed to get one error message (ones) when this happens, in Firefox:

A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete. Script:
/assets/application-93974c42181b2f88f4046c6f3ed118eb.js:14

Other than that, I have nothing to go on.

This files btw does not exist, so it's probably a session file.

I don't have a lot of details. The site is using AJAX GET for refresh of various tables. I'm using bootstrap 2 and jquery-ui a bit. Actually, this error first came around the time I added jquery-ui-draggable to the site, but I can't link the two directly.

I'm completely stumped, any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Can it be because I have several AJAX requests performed with the same interval, using setInterval? I'm gonna try setting them to different intervals, but it can take a lot of time for the error to show itself again.

Comment: did you check the logs of your webserver? apache or nginx...

Comment: No not yet. To be honest I'm not too proficient in reading those. Good suggestion though, I'll check them out. I do get an email anytime an error occurs in the application itself though, and there are none so far (related to this).

Comment: webserver is before your app, so if there is an error at this level, the app cant send anything

Comment: Sounds to me like some of your javascript is causing a problem? Take a look there and check for any infinite loops maybe?

Comment: I agree, seems like it's a javascript problem, since the browser tab stops working. If there is an infinite loop, wouldn't the tab always crash, at a predictable time? That is not the case. One idea I have is that it might be because I have a few AJAX GET calls performed with the same interval (setInterval). Maybe it's a problem with deadlock? None of the calls write anything to the db though.